# Material UI TextField value with \n does not do a line break

Tags: material-ui

I'm trying to load a Material-UI TextField @material-ui/core": "^4.9.11" with a default value string that contains a \n (new line escape character).

However, I don't get the text in the defaultValue to fall on two lines.  The \n escape is just included in the field.  So I want to pass a string that contains a \n to the defaultValue and have it go on two lines of the TextField.

```
import React from "react";
import "./styles.css";
import TextField from "@material-ui/core/TextField";

export default function App() {
  return (
    <div className="App">
      <TextField multiline rows={2} defaultValue="Line1\nLine2" />
    </div>
  );
}
```

[I've got a codesandbox of this here](https://codesandbox.io/s/dank-thunder-xwju8?file=/src/App.js:0-258)

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You can use a variable for that:

```
const val = "Line1\nLine2";
return (
    <div className="App">
        <TextField multiline rows={2} defaultValue={val} />
    </div>
);
```

If you use the string as the value for the property - react will see it a a final string (and not as js string), which means your string is actually `"Line1\\nLine2"`.
To solve this just use a js-string (using a variable, like in the example above) or pass the value of your string as an object:

```
return (
    <div className="App">
        <TextField multiline rows={2} defaultValue={"Line1\nLine2} />
    </div>
);
```